# MySQL IN Statement Hang

Tags: mysql

What I'm attempting to accomplish is return a SELECT statement of ALL duplicates in a table within given filters.

I'm attempting to run the following query but every time I run it my server locks up and it never completes the query. I have no idea what is causing this and some help would be greatly appreciated on either how to fix this or to accomplish my goal in another manner.

EDIT: I've added the EXPLAIN data as requested!
EDIT 2: I've added the CREATE statements as requested!

```
SELECT * 
FROM red_flags 
WHERE customer_number IN (SELECT customer_number 
                          FROM red_flags 
                          GROUP BY customer_number 
                          HAVING COUNT(customer_number) > 1);
```

Execution plan:

```
1   PRIMARY leads   ALL                 80708   Using where
1   PRIMARY customers   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 9   apcard_main.leads.customer_number   1   
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  leads   ALL                 80708   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  customers   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 9   apcard_main.leads.customer_number   1   Using index
```

DDL:

**Table `customers`:**

```
CREATE TABLE `customers` (
  `customer_number` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
  `dealer_id` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `middle_name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address_one` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address_two` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `zip` char(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fico` char(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mail_type` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mail_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `store` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customer_number`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

**Table `leads`:**

```
CREATE TABLE `leads` (
  `lead_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dealer_id` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_number` varchar(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `source` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `source_type` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `home_phone` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mail_type` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `store` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `middle_name` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `zip` char(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fico` char(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mail_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `work_phone` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cell_phone` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address_one` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address_two` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `caller_id` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`lead_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=125587 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

**View `red_flags`:**

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER=`apcard`@`97.83.30.118` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
VIEW `red_flags` AS 
select 
    `leads`.`dealer_id` AS `dealer_id`,
    `customers`.`phone` AS `phone`,
    `leads`.`date` AS `date`,
    `leads`.`time` AS `time`,
    `leads`.`source` AS `source`,
    `leads`.`customer_number` AS `customer_number`,
    `leads`.`caller_id` AS `caller_id`,
    `leads`.`mail_type` AS `mail_type`,
    `leads`.`store` AS `store`,
    `leads`.`last_name` AS `last_name`,
    `leads`.`first_name` AS `first_name`,
    `leads`.`city` AS `city`,
    `leads`.`state` AS `state`,
    `leads`.`zip` AS `zip`,
    `leads`.`fico` AS `fico`,
    `leads`.`mail_date` AS `mail_date`,
    `leads`.`home_phone` AS `home_phone`,
    `leads`.`email` AS `email` 
from (`customers` join `leads`) 
where ((`customers`.`customer_number` = `leads`.`customer_number`) 
  and (`leads`.`date` >= (now() - interval 30 day)))$$
```

Comment: `IN` can be quite slow, but it's hard to say where the trouble lies without seeing what the MySQL query analyzer is doing with the query. To obtain that output, prepend `EXPLAIN` to the query (`EXPLAIN SELECT...`), and edit the result into your question; with the benefit of that info it should be fairly simple to find the trouble.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO

Exists doesn't filter my results correctly 'SELECT * FROM red_flags WHERE EXISTS (SELECT customer_number FROM red_flags WHERE dealer_id = '75' GROUP BY customer_number HAVING COUNT(customer_number) > 1);' for example returns multiple dealer_id's on the select statement instead of filtering correctly.

Comment: there might be other reasons as well. check if you have more connections opened ?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM red_flags f WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM red_flags f2 WHERE f2.customer_number=f.customer_number AND f2.PK <> f.PK);` and add an index on `(customer_number)`

Comment: @akshayb

I've restarted the mysql server, ran the query in multiple ways (Desktop application, directly on website, etc...) All to no avail.

Comment: Is the table MyISAM or InnoDB? Please add the `SHOW CREATE TABLE red_flags ;` output in the question.

Comment: Plus, the `EXPLAIN` shows a `leads` table but I don't see that in the query ...

Comment: red_flags is a view, is that a problem?

Comment: Not really. Add the `CREATE VIEW` then and the `CREATE TABLE` for all the underlying base tables.

Comment: Does `red_flags` have an index on `customer_number`?  Why is `red_flags` not in the EXPLAIN output?

Comment: @RocketHazmat - It is a view as per above comments.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried joining rather than using a subquery?

```
SELECT rf.*
FROM red_flags rf
inner join red_flags rf2
on (rf2.customer_number = rf.customer_number)
group by rf2.customer_number
having count(rf2.customer_number) >1
```

Comment: This works but it only displays DISTINCT customer_number's and doesn't display ALL duplicates like I'm interested in.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I had a poorly formed date filter that was causing it to break when querying with an IN for some reason.

```
leads.date >= now() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

Comment: So, what did you change it into?

Comment: I just removed it and gave up on using that filter for the time being.